# wrap div to every 3 items data coming from database

Tags: php, sql, foreach

```
   <div class="accordion-content default">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 equal">

  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->
  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->
  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->

</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="line-border"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 equal">
  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->
  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->
  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="line-border"> </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-12 equal">

  <!-- <div >content comming from database</div> -->

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-12">
  <div class="line-border"> </div>
  </div>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Above is the HTML code i the div which says content coming from database are the content coming from database and i need to show it 3 per div if in total it comes 19 then it should show 3 each x 6 = 18 and 1 is left that should also be wrapped with the

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare a counter for your loop and reset it every 3 loops. Use the modulo operator to do so.

```
<?php

$i = 0;

foreach($data as $record) {
  if($i == 0) {
    echo '<div class="wrapper">';
  }

  echo $record['some-data'];

  if($i%2 == 0 && $i > 0) {
    echo '</div>';
    $i = 0;
  }

  else {
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Comment: it comes for all 18 items and in 19th item the div doesn close.. it gets closed in the next section.